# Magento 2.3 The images not displayed in Gmail

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email

I need your help I use the module from Mageplaza Smtp and the transactional emails did not show the images in Gmail, but in outlook yes, I inspect the image code in base64 for the images to be correctly displayed in both original emails.

[image: gmail]

[image: outlook]

the first image is in Gmail and the second in outlook

I don't know why only happens in Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too, the problem lies in google using proxy cache for image (gmail). The reason may be that at some point google can't find your image and it will cache it (404). If magento 2 you just need to change the name, or size of the image (so that it is not the same as the original image). Then google will fetch your photo again and it will show up.

Ex with image catalog: php bin/magento catalog:image:resize

Proxy example link gmail image src:

https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/eo_bKe3QYKQHZ70tHCor8K5nFNJL3wgDKDWzH-5y8cfGSVcLZuz1NE_gRUpLi3NzT6c6O847tybDAa0nTN5YJEb4fqiE4Ga6icF9oEyQ74vYL0nfAxKtcK6HflEFlOItus4BrGXM3oTBX3G-KCGOeZ0mO_YBQ1JA_z6LzG-40YMYz_DyWmdpftiBmg=s0-d-e1-ft#https://zemi.vn/media/catalog/product/cache/3aa1bc002e90c1c09f5045ce8ad27d60/o/1/o1cn01ctjzqv28vl9okgauy__2639837995.jpg

Also gmail does not support base64 image.

Answer (score 0):

In Gmail, base64 images will not be displayed because Gmail no longer supports that image format.

Gmail does not support images using data: URLs